# UVA 861: From Backtracking to DP solution

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, backtracking

Problem: Count the number of ways to place K Bishops on N*N chess board.
https://onlinejudge.org/external/8/861.pdf

I came up with the below backtracking solution but it is not fast enough. I do not understand the DP solution recommended on other sites. Can you please help.

In the below code I am exhaustively searching for all solutions using a recursive backtracking approach.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

using Row = vector<bool>;
using Board = vector<Row>;

Board gBoard;

bool isOk(int n, int r, int c) {
  for(int i = r-1, j = c-1; i >= 0 && j >= 0; --i, --j) {
    if(gBoard[i][j]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for(int i = r+1, j = c+1; i < n && j < n; ++i, ++j) {
    if(gBoard[i][j]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for(int i = r-1, j = c+1; i >= 0 && j < n; --i, ++j) {
    if(gBoard[i][j]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for(int i = r+1, j = c-1; i < n && j >= 0; ++i, --j) {
    if(gBoard[i][j]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

void trace(const string &msg) {
  cout << msg << "\n";
  for(int i = 0; i < gBoard.size(); ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < gBoard[i].size(); ++j) {
      cout << gBoard[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
  cout << "\n";
}

void dfs(int n, int k, int r, int c, int cnt, int &sum) {
  if(cnt == k) {
    //trace("OK");
    ++sum;
    return;
  }

  if(c >= n) {
    c = 0;
    r += 1;
  }

  int j = c;
  for(int i = r; i < n; ++i) {
    for( ; j < n; ++j) {
      if(gBoard[i][j]) {
        continue;
      }
      gBoard[i][j] = true;
      if(isOk(n, i,j)) {
        //trace("tmp");
        dfs(n, k, i, j+1, cnt+1, sum);
      }
      gBoard[i][j] = false;
    }
    j = 0;
  }
}

void solve(int n, int k) {
  gBoard.assign(n, Row(n, false));
  int sum = 0;
  dfs(n, k, 0, 0, 0, sum);
  cout << sum << "\n";
}

int main() {
  while(true) {
    int n,k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    if(!n && !k) {
      break;
    }
    solve(n, k);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Actually backtracking is fine for this problem - possible input space is quote small (8*8*8) so you can just pre-compute all answers in a few minutes and answer queries in O(1) after submitting (i.e. https://replit.com/@photon2/uva-861#main.cpp )

Comment: I see that the time limit is only 3 seconds for this problem on UVA online judge.

Comment: Its a valid option in programming competitions, even if it takes a few hours - to pre-compute answers to all or some test cases and then just answer them in O(1), sometimes its the only possible solution

Comment: i get your point. 
thank you